# Apache Ant - include parent directory in fileset

Tags: java, ant, fileset

Is it possible to include a file from a parent directory, seen from the defined dir?

If I define a fileset with a given dir, lets say `/home/user/workspace/src`, is ti possible to include a file e.g `/home/user/anotherworkspace/src/MyJavaClass.java`?

Here the complete example, where the first include esist in the workspace:

```
<fileset id="myfileset" dir="/home/user/workspace/src">
    <include name="util/MyUtilClass.java"/>
    <include name="/home/user/anotherworkspace/src/MyJavaClass.java"/>
</fileset>
```

How to handle the second include?

Comment: You can’t, but you can have multiple filesets in a single path element, including the `<src>` element of `<javac>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that with one fileset, but you can create two sets and then merge them using [`union`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#union) resource collection.

```
<fileset id="myfileset1" dir="/home/user/workspace/src">
    <include name="util/MyUtilClass.java"/>
</fileset>

<fileset id="myfileset2" dir="/home/user/anotherworkspace/src">
    <include name="MyJavaClass.java"/>
</fileset>

<union id="myfileset">
    <resources refid="myfileset1" />
    <resources refid="myfileset2" />
</union>
```

After that you may use `myfileset` as usual.